# ubuntu wont start, vhdx file or virtual machine issue

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wsl2, vhdx

I had a functioning verison of ubuntu running on windows 11 (using ubuntu on windows 11 app)  but just followed some instructions to attach its vhdx file via disk management (I wanted to see inside). now ubuntu wont start with message ...

The operation timed out waiting becuase a response was not received fromthe virtual machine or container.
Error code: WSL/Service/CreateInstance/HCS_E_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT

Any thoughts gratefully received.

Comment: Can you recover from a backup?

Comment: thanks. I m not entirely sure what you mean. I believe its a failure of WSL to start but no i don't have a backup of the vhdx file (14gb)

Comment: I always make a copy of any VM that I may wish to make changes to that I am not sure about

Comment: @Tony I had same error when I tried to recover vhdx image that was uploaded to cloud. Seems like cloud app messed up with file and corrupted it, because later I replaced it with original image and original was working.

Answer (score -1):

Run cmd as administrator and update your wsl

```
wsl --update
```

then go to control panel --> programs --> turn windows features on or off.

then uncheck both windows hypervisor platform and virtual machine platform --> click ok

[image]

open features again and check both of them again windows hypervisor platform and virtual machine platform --> click ok

[image]

once the installation is done, reboot your pc and everything should be working after that.

Comment: thanks much appreciated i did that and restarted twice after reinstalling both of them, however unfortunately ubuntu stil wont start  still with error code timing out
Error code: WSL/Service/CreateInstance/HCS_E_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
so stil  a prpoblme with th .vhdx file although i wsnt able toaccess it and it hasnt been changed (although timestamp on it was updated when i foolishly tried to "attach" to it in disk management and didnt know what i was doing.

Comment: have you tried using the vhdx on a different computer ?